# optimize unix search

Tags: perl, unix, search, optimization

I have 20 files of 500k lines each with 2 numbers per line.
Goal is to get percentage of different pairs (A B) against total number of A number for every A number.
So, result should be A number and his percentage from these files.

For example:

> 1 1
>
> 1 1
>
> 1 1
>
> 1 2

should give me 1 50% (2 different pairs out of 4 A in total).

Following way is too slow:
number of different

```
cat files | sort | uniq -c
```

number of total

```
cat files | cut -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

and then iterate through these results and count percentage per A number.

How to best optimize query (bash/perl) for this?
Also, if this should be done only for subset of these A numbers, how to optimize it?
(for example, for 20k A number, not all 500k)

many thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to sort to perform uniq. This should save you a lot of time.

Comment: @Pavan, I think you mean you don't need `uniq`, since `sort` supports a `-u` option.  (POSIX `uniq` operates on [adjacent lines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/uniq.html), and so sorted input is usually essential.)

Comment: @pilcrow The unique counts are needed, not the order. sort does not provide counts with sort -u. Thanks for clarifying that. I did not know sort was needed for uniq.

Comment: @Pavan, quite right re: counts.  Separately, the OP could get rid of the `cat` calls, with input redirection or just command arguments.

Comment: yes, cat are not needed; thx for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl solution. Try to run it as `script.pl files` and see how fast it goes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;
while (<>) {
    my @nums = split;
    $hash{$nums[0]}{$nums[1]}++;
}

#for my $num (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash) {    
for my $num (keys %hash) {
    my @values = values %{ $hash{$num} };
    my $sum;
    $sum += $_ for @values;
    my $perc = 100 * @values / $sum;
    print "$num $perc%\n";
}
```

Uncomment the line with `sort` (and comment the following one) if you want the output to be sorted by the first number.

Comment: first, many thanks for very fast and useful answer. it took ~1,5min (for loading of data: 65s) for 10M lines. In order to speed it up, additional question: if I need results for example only for 20k (out of 10M), I suppose I should first extract these records and then load data. Is there some better (perl) way of fgrep -f file1 files prior to loading to hash? thanks again

Comment: @user1864748: You might read `file1` into a `%fgrep` hash, then while loading the files, `++ if exists $fgrep{$nums[0]}`. But again, you have to benchmark the solution, plain `fgrep` might be faster.

Comment: fgrep -f finished in ~11s, while loading in hash for ~40s;  11s is fine for me; thx!